# Not sure how to get around 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first

There are a lot of threads on this error, and I've read a ~half dozen of them. (Some of which didn't apply because the relationship wasn't 1:1.) I've tried a few things, but I am still getting the error.

I have two tables, `Account` and `AccountSettings`. They have a 1:1 relationship.  However, `Account` is the primary.  It can exist w/o `AccountSettings`, but not the other way around.

This is what I had originally...

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public int? AccountSettingID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountSettingID ")]
    public virtual AccountSetting AccountSetting { get; set; }
}
```

And then...

```
public class AccountSetting 
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountSettingID { get; set; }
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountID ")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

But that got me the error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'EZHomes.Data.Model.AccountSetting' and 'EZHomes.Data.Model.Account'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

How do I specify `Account` as the principle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Hopefully this will help somebody else.  In the non-primary table:

```
public class AccountSetting 
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountSettingID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("AccountID ")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the Account table/entity to have the AccountSettingId as a foreign key - the relationship is created when you add the AccountSetting and set the AccountId.

Comment: So the reason I added it is because I want to be able to navigate from Acccount to AccountSettings.  Would that be possible without the Account table having the AccountSettingId as a foreign key?

Comment: Yep, there are many ways depending on how you configure EF for LazyLoading, ProxyCreation, use of 'include/load' etc. But you would usually access the data like so: Account.AccountSetting. EF will normally set AccountySetting to be a child object/entity of the Account entity when the data is retrieved from the database and provide navigation both ways via the foreign key.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I thought navigation was only possible from one table to another with a foreign key was specified.